# Black Screen on Logon (windows 7 Home Premium)

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, dell-xps

I have been having some trouble with a dell XPS 15 laptop that I recently purchased. It is under a month old, and a problem has occurred, upon logging on just after start up, the computer will just sit on a black log on screen (with the mouse still visible and active) for a few minutes. it is extremely annoying, especially when I'm in a rush. the laptop is under a month old.

So far, I have tried to update the drivers, all Windows update, and still, nothing. also, it doesn't seem to do it when I log into safe mode, or if it does, it will do it for less than 10 seconds, then load the desktop (in normal boot, it usually takes a few minutes). I have also run a number of the inbuilt diagnostics, but found no errors.

I want to avoid having to do a system restore for as long as I can. does anyone know anything that can help?

(The laptop is running a 500GB SSD, 2GB Nvidia 640M, 8GB RAM, 3rd gen i7 Quad Core with 8 threads)

Comment: Are you aware of any background programs loading during startup?

Comment: i checked msconfig, nothing unusual by the looks of it

Comment: Are there normal beeps during POST?